# How to declare a shared attribute using threads::shared?

Tags: multithreading, perl, moose

Using [threads::shared](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads::shared), it is possible to declare a shared variable like this:

```
my $n_lines_waiting: shared = 0;
```

Using Moose, attributes are declared via 'has':

```
has 'p_queue' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Thread::Queue', default => sub{ return Thread::Queue->new(); });
```

Is there a way to combine threads::shared and Moose? I would like to use that nifty syntax of Moose to declare an attribute that can be shared between threads.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as changing your default to include that same syntax:

```
'default' => sub {
    my $queue :shared = Thread::Queue->new();
    return $queue
},
```

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, this did not work. Declaring the attribute with the method above results in different values per thread. It seems that accessing the variable as a moose attribute behaves as if it were not shared.

Comment: @capfan I tried it and it worked for me. What does your code look like that's using this object?

Comment: sure, here you go: https://gist.github.com/asb-capfan/829ebcce1b91988c7099#file-tl-threads-queue-moose-pl